# Workaround for no array_map for keys and values

Tags: php

I'd like a function that fills an array from a callback supplying key and value, to looplessly refactor e.g. this:

```
 foreach(array_slice($argv,1) as $arg)
 if( preg_match('~^([^=]*)=([^=]*)$~',$arg,$matches)) $_SERVER[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
```

What's the nearest available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_SERVER += array_reduce(array_slice($argv, 1), function (array $args, $arg) {
    return $args + preg_match('~^([^=]*)=([^=]*)$~', $arg, $m) ? [$m[1] => $m[2]] : [];
}, []);
```

Whether this is really anymore sensible than a straight `foreach` loop is very debatable, but hey...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to walk the array and apply the results to the superglobal.

```
array_walk(array_slice($argv,1), function ($val) {
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $val, 2);
    if (isset($value){
         $_SERVER[$key] = $value;
    }
});
```

If you had wanted to do something like this targeting a non super global you would just need to add `use (&$array)` after the function keyword in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, but explode can give a different result.